Accidentally Deleted ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 – Unable to Run Any Commands or Connect to Server
Issue :
I accidentally deleted the file ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  ( is in /usr/lib64/ ) on my Linux server, which has now rendered all commands unusable, and I can no longer connect to the server. Since this library file is essential for dynamic linking, almost every command I attempt fails with errors related to missing dependencies.
System Information:
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
File Deleted: ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
What I've Tried:

Rebooting the server (same issue persists).
Accessing through SSH and local terminal commands, but neither works
due to missing    dependencies.

My Goal: To restore the ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 file so that the server can run commands again and operate normally.

Did you delete the symbolic link, or the file it points to? Can you run the statically-linked busybox binary? See also How to recover ld-linux file when i don't have any temporary copy of that

I have deleted just symlink . executed command inside /usr/lib64/rm -f *.
